# 'aggs' query to count only what we need on Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I have a query which counts the number of messages that tag both the ne_id 404 AND any other events.id (these are my company's norms, forgive me if it is hard to understand) like this:

```
{
  "query": {
  "filtered": {  
    "filter" : {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {"term": {"events.ne_id": 404}},
          {"terms": {"events.impact_status": [1, 2]}},
          {"range": {"published_at": { "gte": str(start_date+"T00:00:00"), "lte": str(end_date+"T23:59:59")}}}

        ]
      }
     }
    }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "by_events":{
            "terms": {
                "size":0,
                "field": "events.id"
            },
}
}
}
```

The problem I have with this query is that it does not only give me the messages that tag the ne_id 404, but also other ne_ids, it only guarantees that the messages HAVE ne_id 404 in it, so I cannot perform the 'aggs' query as the event_ids might be paired with other ne_ids not the ne_id 404.

Is there any other way that I can adjust the query so that the 'aggs' query only count the event_ids that paired with ne_id 404?

Here is a screenshot of the 'events' field in Elasticsearch:
[image: Elasticsearch example]

Comment: what is the mapping of your `events` field? simple `object` or `nested` object?

Comment: it is a nested object @val

Comment: If it's really nested, then your query won't work as all your queries with `events.xyz` must be inside a `nested` query.

Comment: may you suggest me how to fixed it as I am a real beginner with ES...?

Comment: Please show what you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`